# How to cluster different strings using machine learning in python

Tags: string, text, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset that consists of building names.e.g {Hill View,Hills View,Hill Apartment...}.I want to cluster these strings using machine learning.for eg after clustering one cluster should contain strings which are similar or somewhat similar {Hills,Hill...}.I have tried various scikit algorithms like K-means,Affinity Propagation etc but did not succedd.Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Machine Learning isn't magic!
It uses mathematical objects and functions.

You need first steps - usually known as Data Mining - which kind of consists in:

- Transforming any input (string, pictures, videos, anything...) to
  numbers (vectors, matrices or any relevent structure).
- Defining distance and similarity between vectors (= distance between the numerical representation of your input ~= distance between string, pictures, videos, anything).

This is not trivial and can be done different ways depending on your data/objectives.

Since I don't know your background in CS/ML/Maths, I could just give you a general approach which is, in a general case, quite good/easy.

That is the general speach, in pratice this problematic is complex and there's a lot to learn on that.
You will most probably need the **edit distance** which is the most intuitive distance between words, you should also consider **stemming** which.

Can't give a better anwser without more information on data/context.

Regards

Comment: Got it.Modified the document clustering to string clustering using kmeans..It works now:).Thankyou anyways.:)

Answer (score 0):

Got it:
Please follow this link for document clustering:
http://brandonrose.org/clustering
It gives an exact precise description.In order to convert it into normal string clustering where you have a list of names(strings) just pass the the list in place of the title list passed in the explanation.Also replace each occurrence of synopses list in the example with the list you want to cluster(in this case the list containing the strings to be clustered)

You can skip few snippets since they provide extra information.Keeping them in the code will not harm you final clusters.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Naive Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) algorithm for  phrase clustering, for example in php

```
$classifier = new \Niiknow\Bayes();

// teach it positive phrases

$classifier->learn('amazing, awesome movie!! Yeah!! Oh boy.', 'positive');
$classifier->learn('Sweet, this is incredibly, amazing, perfect, great!!', 'positive');

// teach it a negative phrase

$classifier->learn('terrible, shitty thing. Damn. Sucks!!', 'negative');

// now ask it to categorize a document it has never seen before

$classifier->categorize('awesome, cool, amazing!! Yay.');
// => 'positive'
```

relevant library at [here](https://github.com/niiknow/bayes)